# Edit Custom Email Template before sending

Tags: email-template

I've setup several template emails that are the custom format.  I'd like to be able to choose this template from a lead and edit before sending.  Right now when I click the custom template it doesn't allow me to edit like I can when the template is Text or HTML (letterhead).

I really just want to send an HTML email without a letterhead but that isn't an option and I don't want to send plain text.

Is there a way to do this?   Any help would be great!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? It seems unusual that you can do this for HTML (with letterheads) templates but not for custom tempaltes.